# Rails + jQuery UI dialog box only opening the first time

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

In a scenario i am opening up the dialog box on checking the checkbox,

on first attempt it works fine(on first check on checkbox), but when i uncheck the checkbox and check it again dialog box is not opening,

this is the code i have used to open dialog box,

```
    var target = '<%= url_for(user_path)%>';
    var shared_target = target + "?share=" + this.id
    var dialog = "user_" + this.id

    $("#"+dialog).dialog({width: 460, minHeight: 300});
    $("#"+dialog).load(shared_target)
```

please advise me how to resolve this

thanks

Comment: May help you to use a line by line debugger like firebug for firefox.  With that you can see exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the catch would be that the "uncheck" of the checkbox is not going through properly. Can you share some more details on how that has been handled.

Make sure that the state variable holding checkbox value is "reset" once its unchecked.

Comment: $('.user').click(function(){                                            var thischeck = $(this);    if (thischeck.is(':checked')) {   above code } }

Comment: please guide me how to reset state variable holding checkbox